# Retrieve the instance created by class_based_view

Tags: python, django

Django documentation specify `as_view` method in 
[class-based-views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/intro/)

> as_view() class method creates **an instance** of the class and calls its dispatch() method.

I attempt to print the instance.
 For illustration:

```
 # urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from myapp.views import MyView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about/$', MyView.as_view()),
]


#views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')
```

I added a `print` statement to `views.py`:

```
class MyView(View):
    print(self)
    def get(self, request):
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')
```

It reports `NameError`.

How can I print the instance created by class 'View'?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Are you the same person as https://stackoverflow.com/users/8445949/acejohn? You're asking very similar questions.

Comment: The quality of your answers is inconsistent. It indicates that many persons are working on your single account. I reported it to system.@DanielRoseman

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `__repr__` or `__str__` method of the view (those methods are by default inherited by every python class). There are 2 options:

1. Get the representation (`__repr__` do you get it yet? :D) every time a REST method gets called:

   ```
   class MyView(View):
       def get(self, request):
           # <view logic>
           print(self.__repr__())
           return HttpResponse(result)
   ```

   or return it in the `HttpResponse`:

   ```
   class MyView(View):
       def get(self, request):
           # <view logic>
           result['self_repr'] = self.__repr__()
           return HttpResponse(result)
   ```
2. Get the representation of the class each time it gets instantiated:

   ```
   class MyView(View):
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           print(self.__repr__())
   ```

The end result though will be something like this:

```
<my_app.views.MyView object at 0x7f63b5e05668>
```

which is not very helpful. You can override the `__str__()` method to return something more specific but that is up to you!

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to access self outside its scope

```
class MyView(View):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print self

    def get(self, request):
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that will not print much usefulness like:

```
<app.views.MyView object at 0x000001720304E128>
```

Of course you can make it better by defining:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.attibutehere
```

However I get the feeling that you are looking for the implementation details of the class. This is done by a process called "introspection".

As an example amongst other powerful commands there is a dir() command which could be used like this from the command line:

```
project location>python manage.py shell
>>>from polls.views import IndexView
>>>iv=IndexView()
>>>dir(iv)
['__class__', ...whole bunch of interesting stuf here... , 'template_name_suffix']
>>> iv.__class__
<class 'polls.views.IndexView'>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
class MyView(View):
    print(self)
    def get(self, request):
        print('self:', self)
        return HttpResponse('result')
```

Comment: While writing the answer, you should consider the indentation and for this particular answer even it would run.